# Windows Azure Shared Access Signatures SAS

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm developing a filesharing website and I have a couple of questions regarding Windows Azure Shared Access Signatures.

**About my website:** Registered users can upload, share and store their files using blob storage. The files can be up to 2GB in size so I want the upload and download to be as fast as possible. It's 
also important that the administartion cost for me as a host is at its minimum. User stored files must be private.

I'm OK with using SAS URI for uploads, but for downloads I'm abit spooked.

**Questions:**

**1.** Users can store files on their account and these files should only be accessed by that user. If I were to use SAS URI download here, the files will always be available with an URI as long as 
the URI lives, (doesnt require you to be logged in if you know the URI, you can just download the file). This is quite scary if you want the file to be private. I know the signature in the SAS URI 
is "HMAC computed over a string-to-sign and key using the SHA256 algorithm, and then encoded using Base64 encoding", is this safe? Is it acceptable to use SAS URI for downloads even if 
the files are private? Should I instead stream the file between the server and website, (this will be much more safe but the speed will suffer and the administration cost will rise).

**2.** How much slower and how much more will it cost if I stream the downloads between (server, website, user) instead of using SAS, (server directly to user)?

**3.** If I set the SAS URI expiry time to 1 hour and the download takes longer than 1 hour, will the download cancel if the download started before the expiry time?

**4.** If my website is registered at x.azurewebsites.net and I'm using a purchased domain so I can access my website at www.x.com, is it possible to make the SAS URI's look somethinglike this: 
https://x.com/blobpath instead of https://x.blob.core.windows.net/blobpath, (my guess is no..).

Sorry for the wall of text!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There's nothing that stops someone from sharing a URI, whether with or without a SAS. So from a safety perspective, if you leave the expiry date far-off into the future, the URI will remain accessible with the SAS-encoded URI. From an overall security perspective: Since your blob is private, nobody else will have access to the blob without a SAS-encoded URI. To limit SAS use: If, instead of being issued a long-standing SAS URI, the user visited a web page (or API) to request file access, you could generate a new SAS URI for a smaller time window; at this point, the end user would still be able to direct-access the blob without streaming the content through the VM (this just adds an extra network hop for obtaining the URI, along with whatever is needed to host the web / API server). Also related to security: If you use a *stored access policy*, you have the ability to modify access after issuing the SAS, rather than embedding start+end time directly into the SAS URI itself (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee393341.aspx) info about access policies).
2. You'll incur the cost of the VM(s) used for fronting the URI requests. Outbound bandwidth costs are the same as using blob access directly: You pay for outbound bandwidth only. Performance will be affected by many things if going through a VM: VM size, VM resource use (e.g. if your VM is running at 100% CPU, you might see performance degredation), number of concurrent accesses, etc.
3. Yes, if the user hits expiry time, the link is no longer valid.
4. Yes, you can use a SAS combined with custom domain names used with storage. See [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/) for more information about setting up custom domain names for storage.

Comment: Thank you. Wow stored access policy is just what i was looking for. If I understand it correctly, I am able to update the expiry time after the URI has been created? I can also delete it manually after some time?

Comment: Are you sure about #3?  My impression was that the policy would be checked when the initial request was made, and if it was valid at that time would be allowed to proceed.  I don't see how it could check the policy again and terminate the connection if no other requests were made.

Comment: Regarding the edge case of whether a download would continue: Remember that a download could consist of multiple REST API calls. And each call (transaction) has headers including authorization (with SAS being a form of authorization). So if a subsequent call is sent, and the SAS key has expired, I would suspect this subsequent call is invalid.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting the read operation would fail in the middle of download, if the expiry time were reached during the operation but after authorization. Once the header is checked, there's nothing that's re-checking that authorization header during the actual read. And since an individual read transaction could take up to two minutes, it's entirely possible the time window closes *during* the read (but that should be ok).

Comment: I have a follow-up question regarding Stored Access Policy if you feel up for it:)


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549988/windows-azure-stored-access-policy-remove