# Windows Azure Stored Access Policy Remove

Tags: windows, azure

I want to download blobs using Shared access signatures, SAS.

I also want to be able to remove active SAS URI's and, if I understand it correctly, I must use Stored Access Policy for this.

What confuses me is how I can remove a policy. I also read you can only have 5 stored access policies active?

My goal here is to be able to remove an active SAS URI. The only way I can think of accomplishing this is to remove the policy that the SAS URI is linked with, right? If I have over hundreds of files in my blob storage, how in the world can I make this work? I can't have one policy for each blob right? 5 is the maximum policies?

This code demonstrates how I add a policy and how I create a SAS URI that uses this policy, which users can download from.

```
static void CreateSharedAccessPolicy(CloudBlobContainer container)
{
    //Create a new stored access policy and define its constraints.
    SharedAccessBlobPolicy sharedPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
    {
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(10),
        Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List
    };

    //Get the container's existing permissions.
    BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();

    //Add the new policy to the container's permissions.
    permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Clear();
    permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add("PolicyName", sharedPolicy);
    container.SetPermissions(permissions);
}

static string GetBlobSasUriWithPolicy(CloudBlobContainer container, string policyName)
{
    //Get a reference to a blob within the container.
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("file_name");

    //Generate the shared access signature on the blob.
    string sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(null, "PolicyName");

    //Return the URI string for the container, including the SAS token.
    return blob.Uri + sasBlobToken;
}
```

One last question, how do I remove a policy? Is it as simple as:

```
    permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Remove("PolicyName");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My goal here is to be able to remove an active SAS URI. The only way I
>   can think of accomplishing this is to remove the policy that the SAS
>   URI is linked with, right?

Partly correct. Removing the access policy is one way to do it. Other would be to change the name of the policy (policy identifier). For example if the policy identifier is `mypolicy` then changing it to `mypolicy1` would have the same effect as removing the policy.

> If I have over hundreds of files in my blob storage, how in the world
>   can I make this work?

As you may already know, access policy is defined at the blob container level and not at the blob level. Removing/invalidating an access policy would make invalidate SAS URL for all blobs in that container.

> I can't have one policy for each blob right? 5 is the maximum
>   policies?

That is correct.

> One last question, how do I remove a policy? Is it as simple as:
>   permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Remove("PolicyName");

That is correct. Make sure you save it back though. You can use something like:

```
        var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
        var blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container-name");
        var containerPermissions = container.GetPermissions();
        containerPermissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Remove("access-policy-id");
        container.SetPermissions(containerPermissions);
```

Comment: Good answer, thank you. Just to be clear, keeping track of over hundreds of SAS URI's and manually deleting them is NOT possible then? I will gladly accept your answer if you give me one last comment ;)

Comment: If you're using container access policy and all blobs are in the same container, then you don't need to delete/invalidate the SAS URL on 100s of blobs. Invalidating the access policy on a container would simply invalidate the SAS URL of all blobs in that container. HTH.

Comment: Yes but what I want is to be able to delete just _one_ SAS URI. I dont want the policy to reset on _all_ the blobs. This is impossible to accomplish because of policy limit, yes?

Comment: I think you're right. However I would like to know more about your application so that I can suggest some alternative.